# Multiple conditions for starting and ending loop

Tags: r

I have a data set that has around 4 million rows. An example of the data is as shown below. I would like a run a loop with multiple start and end conditions.

The loop should first look for speed=0 and load=0, then it must detect a change in load (ex sl no = 6 where speed = 0 but load is not equal to zero). Once a load change is detected the loop should start copying from the previous 3 rows ie. sl no. 3. The loop should end when there is speed detected (speed and payload are not equal to zero)and it should copy the next 3 rows. Therefore, I need the loop to start copying from sl no.3-12. The loop should again repeat and look for the starting 2 conditions.

```
Sl.No    Speed    Load
1        20       50
2        20       10
3         0       0 
4         0       0
5         0       0
6         0       60
7         0       120
8         0       180
9         10      180
10        11      180
11        20      180
12        25      180
```

Comment: provide the expected output to make your intended question clearer. refer to [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You should write something like this (which is a nested loop) and then use index i and j in them in order to go back and forward:

```
for(i in seq_along(data)){
  if(#your condition e.g. data[i][1]==0 & data[i][2]==0)
  {  
    # do something with data[i]
    # do something with data[i-1]
    # do something with data[i-2]
    # do something with data[i-3]
    j <- i + 1
    while(#your other condition: e.g. data[j][1]==...)
    {
        # do something with data[j]
        j <- j + 1
    }
    # Next three:
    # do something with data[j]
    # do something with data[j+1]
    # do something with data[j+2]
}
```

Note that instead of using usual foreach style loop in R: for(item in data), I am going over the indexes.